# How save "modification" that doesn't affect the link on a web page

Tags: html, web

On my university website, when I pull down the drop-down menu to display my schedule (which is quite long), the website shows my schedule, but the link doesn't change and when I refresh the page, I have to make to pull down the drop-down menu again if I want to display my schedule again.

Here's a simple example that I've found on google translate. [When I click here ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SHb7.png)

[A menu is displaying without modifying the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucPG7.png)

So when I click where my mouse is on the first picture, it displays a menu that doesn't affect the link, but when I refresh it disappears.

I think it's the same thing that on my university website. How can I manage it ?

Thank you !

Comment: There is a lot of ways to import content to a page, so please let us know what you have tried so far,  with at least a minimum exemple of your code, any doubts please read it https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If you are trying to just display a menu or import content without change the link, it can be done with plain javascript, is it what you want?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.